# Unable to Connect MTS Mblaze modem in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, usb, 12.10, internet-connection

I am using Ubuntu for 1st time and I do have an modem MTS Mblaze in India which I am using in Windows.

But when I tried to connect in Ubuntu 12.10 using give default method (i.e. choose country, modem type, connection, add details and then connect) its not working.

Then i came over another solution at http://www.e-dirts.com/2012/how-to-setup-mts-mblaze-usb-modem-in-ubuntu-gnulinux/

But no installation of `CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.2-SSTL-ALL-ubuntu.deb` happens at all. Is it because I'm using 12.10 version while its tested using 12.04 version.

And does that another 'Advanced user method' can be followed without internet?

Comment: I am also facing this issue in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system. Error is Modem disconnected. Please help me.

Comment: did you install `CrossPlatformUI-V2.1.2-SSTL-ALL-ubuntu.deb` file

Answer (score 0):

I have been using MTS Mblaze connection for quite sometime. I have never felt the need of a third party tool to get to use MTS Mblaze connection in India. Once you connect your usb-modem at system startup, you should be able to see your MTS Mblaze usb device listed under your network. All you need to do is chose the MTS Mblaze connection. Ubuntu does automatically configure it for you. If necessary, have a reboot and wake up your USB modem connection up and running.

Comment: are you using Ubuntu 12.10 version?

Answer (score -1):

Try sakis3g. It's some kind of an all in one script. http://www.sakis3g.org/

Comment: This answer does not provide adequate details of what this software or script does, nor what it provides.  Therefore, it does not really "answer" anything.